on submit I am getting only last array of object not complete data
I am displaying data fetched from API in table, which has inputs as fields to edit the data.
It has multiple data records fetched via API , post changes of the record I want to update the changes done by user and pass it to API for update.
    {Result.map((item,index) => (
                    <tr key={index} className="table-Result-Data">
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationId"
                          value={item.acd_ap_id}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationName"
                          value={item.acd_ap_nm}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="gsid"
                          value={item.acd_ap_gsid}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Sequence"
                          value={item.acd_con_seq}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationDl"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_appl_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                          defaultValue={item.acd_appl_dl}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          name="leadManagerDl"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_lead_manager_dl}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_lead_manager_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          name="systemOwnerNameDl"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_system_owner_name_dl}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_system_owner_name_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="dataCenterName"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_dc_name}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_dc_name = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="qaSftpId"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_id}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_qa_sftp_id = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="qaSftpPwd"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="prodSftpId"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_id}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_prod_sftp_id = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="prodSftpPwd"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="updatedUser"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_upd_usr}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_upd_usr = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" className="submit_Update" />

The result has four data I accessing it using the formdata
export async function action({ request }) {
  console.log(" APDB functioncalled");
  const formData = await request.formData();
  console.log(formData)
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(data)
}

I submit I am getting only the last values of result not able to all the objects of results, is due to map function or what?
How I can resolve it?

All the inputs within the form necessarily should have unique name attributes. Your current implementation uses the same name attribute for each mapped set of inputs, so only the last mapped inputs are the ones that set the form data values.
Appending the array index is one way to disambiguate all the inputs.
Example:
{result.map((item, index) => (
  <tr key={index} className="table-Result-Data">
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"applicationId-" + index}
        value={item.acd_ap_id}
        readOnly
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"applicationName-" + index}
        value={item.acd_ap_nm}
        readOnly
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"gsid-" + index}
        value={item.acd_ap_gsid}
        readOnly
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"Sequence-" + index}
        value={item.acd_con_seq}
        readOnly
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"applicationDl-" + index}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_appl_dl = e.target.value;
        }}
        defaultValue={item.acd_appl_dl}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="email"
        name={"leadManagerDl-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_lead_manager_dl}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_lead_manager_dl = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="email"
        name={"systemOwnerNameDl-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_system_owner_name_dl}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_system_owner_name_dl = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"dataCenterName-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_dc_name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_dc_name = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"qaSftpId-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_id}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_qa_sftp_id = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"qaSftpPwd-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"prodSftpId-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_id}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_prod_sftp_id = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"prodSftpPwd-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={"updatedUser-" + index}
        defaultValue={item.acd_upd_usr}
        onChange={(e) => {
          item.acd_upd_usr = e.target.value;
        }}
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
))}

When submitting the form the action should be able to access all the fields and may look similar to this:
console.log(data);

{
    "applicationId-0": "sdkflksdls",
    "applicationName-0": "lskdlsdlsflkj",
    "gsid-0": "sdlkjdsflj",
    "Sequence-0": "dld[-04m",
    "applicationDl-0": "09fiblwen",
    "leadManagerDl-0": "sdp9@upmweg",
    "systemOwnerNameDl-0": "pse@knlen",
    "dataCenterName-0": "slkjeg;`",
    "qaSftpId-0": "p0jwew.",
    "qaSftpPwd-0": "l;jesf;l;",
    "prodSftpId-0": "ndvo;iwen",
    "prodSftpPwd-0": "odsilewn",
    "updatedUser-0": "lisfklf",
    "applicationId-1": "laflknnk",
    "applicationName-1": "lkesdp90efn",
    "gsid-1": "9035lkn0",
    "Sequence-1": "90welkeflkj",
    "applicationDl-1": "-0eoermg;e",
    "leadManagerDl-1": "poele@smflw",
    "systemOwnerNameDl-1": "lkewl@gkeln",
    "dataCenterName-1": "lksdmrh[oklme",
    "qaSftpId-1": "098senfk",
    "qaSftpPwd-1": "sdkjfnwle",
    "prodSftpId-1": "-9ergm.dr",
    "prodSftpPwd-1": "09o34j64;lkn",
    "updatedUser-1": "lkwe;l;ml;v"
}

To "re-pack" the data back into arrays of field data you can iterate the data object's entries and reconstruct the arrays using some string manipulation to "reverse-engineer" the field key and used array index.
Example:
const repackData = (data) =>
  Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    // grab data key and appended index
    const [dataKey, index] = key.split("-");

    // Create data object if it doesn't exist yet
    if (!acc[index]) {
      acc[index] = {};
    }

    // Update data object's property with value
    acc[index][dataKey] = value;

    return acc;
  }, []);



const data = {
  "applicationId-0": "sdkflksdls",
  "applicationName-0": "lskdlsdlsflkj",
  "gsid-0": "sdlkjdsflj",
  "Sequence-0": "dld[-04m",
  "applicationDl-0": "09fiblwen",
  "leadManagerDl-0": "sdp9@upmweg",
  "systemOwnerNameDl-0": "pse@knlen",
  "dataCenterName-0": "slkjeg;`",
  "qaSftpId-0": "p0jwew.",
  "qaSftpPwd-0": "l;jesf;l;",
  "prodSftpId-0": "ndvo;iwen",
  "prodSftpPwd-0": "odsilewn",
  "updatedUser-0": "lisfklf",
  "applicationId-1": "laflknnk",
  "applicationName-1": "lkesdp90efn",
  "gsid-1": "9035lkn0",
  "Sequence-1": "90welkeflkj",
  "applicationDl-1": "-0eoermg;e",
  "leadManagerDl-1": "poele@smflw",
  "systemOwnerNameDl-1": "lkewl@gkeln",
  "dataCenterName-1": "lksdmrh[oklme",
  "qaSftpId-1": "098senfk",
  "qaSftpPwd-1": "sdkjfnwle",
  "prodSftpId-1": "-9ergm.dr",
  "prodSftpPwd-1": "09o34j64;lkn",
  "updatedUser-1": "lkwe;l;ml;v",
};

const repackData = (data) =>
  Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    // grab data key and appended index
    const [dataKey, index] = key.split("-");

    // Create data object if it doesn't exist yet
    if (!acc[index]) {
      acc[index] = {};
    }

    // Update data object's property with value
    acc[index][dataKey] = value;

    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(repackData(data));




Hi @Drew Reese it is working fine but now how to segregate the form data separately and pass to API

@user23154524 You'd need to process that data object if you wanted to convert it back to something that looked like arrays of form data. I've updated my answer with an example implementation.

yes it is resolved
